# Limiting query result

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code..

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th>
                        <th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                    <?php
    require("conn.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

     echo "<td>$line[4]<table><tr><td> $line[1]</td><td> $line[2]</td></tr></table></td>";


                    }
                    ?>

                    </tr>


                </table>
```

Now I am displaying only 7 records for only one week. I want to display first 7 records in first row and second 7 record in second row and so on..So how do I do that in my code. I am making changes but chages design and I dont want to change the design.

With above code result is like following ..
[image]

I want to display only 7 records up to saturday and next 7 records in next row..

Comment: you can add a `LIMIT 7` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th>
                        <th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                    <?php
    require("conn.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM temp)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $i=1;

    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<tr>";
         if($i<=7){
                  echo  "<td>$line[$i]</td>";
                  $i++;   
                   }
           echo "</tr>;
     }

           //condition for next week 
                $i=0;
     ?>      
    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Not working..I am using $i just for looping. There is no data in $i.

Comment: can u elaborate your code a bit? I mean the above code I have written with certain assumptions that $i is an index and the values for weekdays in $line array you can get from 0 - 6 index values ofcourse you can alter /change this code according to your requirements

Comment: Suppose $i is not there and then what would be the solution?? I am not getting anything in $i.

Comment: why are u creating another table here:   echo "<td><table><tr><td>$line[4]</td></tr></table>";